# nest graphql ts uses jwt to complete login registration and has a problem

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSEYF.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy9di.png)This place is mainly do not know where the problem, why can not get it

I carried out a log test but the results were not satisfactory, the error was not visible

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.